# How to Change the Alpha Mask of a Cut-Out Shader at Runtime in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, alpha, masking

I'm using code to swap skinned meshes at runtime. I'm having an issue with the skin bleeding through layers of clothing.

From my research, there are a few solutions:

1. Turn the body mesh into several objects: Chest, Waist, Glutes and Thighs, and Shoulders (for example). Hide these body objects when the clothing item is attached. (not a bad solution, but I think it will make weight painting the base mesh tedious. I also don't like how it would create more gameobjects in the scene as this doesn't seem optimal).
2. Use shapekeys to deform the vertices when a piece of clothing is applied. This is a promising solution and would probably work well. Especially as you can edit shapekeys with a slider which would give a lot of flexibility.
3. Make alpha maps that hide the areas of the body texture that poke through different items of clothing. Using the default, cut-out shader in Unity, swap out the diffuse alpha at runtime to hide the parts of the body that bleed through. This approach is used by Ootii in this asset: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/mount-points-16318

I understand how to implement the first two options, but I'm stumped on the third option. I have purchased Ootii's asset, but the code is a mystery to me.

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to change the alpha of a diffuse texture in a cut-out shader at runtime?